# No instance of function template "std::make_pair" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Is it legal to use unordered_map for a pair type like `<int, vector<vector<int>>>`? Visual Studio warns me "No instance of function template "std::make_pair matches the argument list" in line 16 (`map.insert(make_pair<int, vector<vector<int>>>(i + m, tt))`):

```
void test(vector<int>& nums) 
{
    unordered_map<int, vector<vector<int>>> map;
    unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> map2;
    vector<vector<int>> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int m = i + 1; m < nums.size(); m++)
        {
            if (!map.count(i + m))
            {
                vector<int> t{ i, m };
                vector<vector<int>> tt;
                tt.push_back(t);
                map.insert(make_pair<int, vector<vector<int>>>(i + m, tt));
                map2.insert(make_pair<int, unordered_set<int>>(i + m, unordered_set<int>(i - m)));
            }
            else if (map2.at(i + m).count(i - m) || map2.at(i + m).count(m - i))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                map.at(i + m).push_back(vector<int>{i, m});
                map2.at(i + m).insert(i - m);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be `std::make_pair()`: you should have this template deduce the appropriate types:

```
map.insert(std::make_pair(i + m, tt));
```

According to the C++ standard 20.3.3 [pair.spec] paragraph 9 `std::make_pair()` is declared something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
std::pair<???, ???> make_pair(F&& first, S&& second)
```

(with suitable types filled in for the `???`). However, the types you specified wouldn't match the arguments, indeed! If you wanted to specify the types correctly, you'd use

```
std::make_pair<int, std::vector<std::vector<int>>&>(i + m, tt)
```

Comment: Why exactly is `std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` required to be a reference to match the types correctly ?

Comment: @SebTu: the template parameters are specified via a forwarding reference (whose type is meant to be deduced). When the type is specified explicitly it is combined with the `&&`. This, when using `X` for the type you'd have a parameter of type `X&&` to which only rvalues can bind. Using `X&` gives `X& &&` which becomes `X&` after reference collapsing to which non-`const` lvalues can bind. The parameter `tt` is a non-`const` lvalue of type `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. You could also add a `const` in front of the `&` but it isn't necessary in this case. ... and best you leave the types off!

Comment: Note that the code can also be corrected by using `std::move(tt)`, which should probably be done for efficiency's sake anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to pass type arguments to `make_pair`; it is supposed to deduce them, then forward them to a pair of values.

Simply remove the `<int, vector<vector<int>>>` portion after `make_pair`.

You can pass types and make it work, but the rules are arcane, and the procedure useless; by passing types, you are doing it wrong.

If you want to pass the types, replace `make_pair` with `pair` and construct directly.  The point of `make_pair` is *not* having to pass the types.

If you want to know more about this particular error and how make pair works, read up about template function type deduction and forwarding references.